# TestCafe Studio and an Electron application

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Perhaps a bit of a dim question, but here goes. Can TestCafe Studio be used to create tests for Electron based apps? Having played with it a little, I can see no clear way to do this, and it only offers the usual browsers. Is this a bit too niche? I understand that open-source TestCafe itself is capable of this, but I'm demoing Studio to see if it's suitable for someone who has little experience.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, TestCafe Studio does not support recording tests for Electron applications. We will consider this functionality as a possible enhancement for our future updates.